# Помогите исправить ошибку python

Tags: python, opencv, поиск, скриншот

Я новичок в программировании и использовал чат гпт для написания программы. Суть программы заключается в поиске смайликов  на экране и выводе их количества.но каждый раз после запуска возникают новые проблемы, в этот раз возникла ошибка

> Exception has occurred: error
> OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:196: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
> File "F:\import numpy as np.ini", line 12, in process_frame
> template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "F:\import numpy as np.ini", line 30, in 
> frame = process_frame()
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:196: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

вот сам код:

```
import pyautogui
import cv2
import imutils

# Функция для обработки скриншота и поиска смайликов
def process_frame():
    frame = np.array(pyautogui.screenshot())

    # Загружаем шаблон смайлика
    template = cv2.imread('cat_emoji.png')
    template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Находим смайлики  на скриншоте
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray_frame, template_gray, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = 0.8
    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

    # Рисуем прямоугольники вокруг найденных смайликов
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(frame, pt, (pt[0] + template.shape[1], pt[1] + template.shape[0]), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    cv2.putText(frame, f'Количество смайликов : {len(loc[0])}', (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    return frame

# Основной цикл программы
while True:
    frame = process_frame()

    # Отображение обработанного скриншота
    cv2.namedWindow('Processed Frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow('Processed Frame', 800, 600)  # Изменение размера окна
    cv2.imshow('Processed Frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Очень прошу помочь, заранее спасибо

Comment: [cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'](https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.en.f4f83011-65c26922-4acd506a-74722d776562/https/github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/933)

Comment: @ΝNL993, ТС написал, что он новичок. Соответственно, не смог сам разобрасться в traceback ошибки.
@Mr.My_name, у тебя не считалось изображение в `template = cv2.imread('cat_emoji.png')`. Проверь путь. Можешь еще проверьть результат считывания с помощью `if template.empty()`

Comment: И обращаться за помощью к железяке aka chatGPT — _очень_ плохая идея. Даже если оно ухитриться написать вам код, который не вылетит сразу, будете схватываться за голову потом. Самим надо писать, самим.